Numbering system using counter in css
I want to create a counter or numbering system in HTML and CSS, but the sub-counter isn't working properly.
This is what i have done so far, im gonna make a new counter in body and then a sub-counter in a class name second and then increase each of them in Pseudo-elements.


body {
  counter-reset: css-counters 0; 
}
.first {
  position: relative;
  left: 90px;
  top: 10px;
  right: auto;
  bottom: auto;
  padding: 10px;
}

.first:before {
  counter-increment: css-counters; 
  content: "Điều " counter(css-counters) " "; 
  position: absolute; 
  left: -60px; 
  top: 0; 
}

.first .second {
  counter-reset: sub-counter; 
  position: relative; 
}

.first .second:first-child {
  counter-reset: sub-counter; 
}

.first .second:not(:first-child) {
  counter-increment: sub-counter 0;
}

.first .second:before {
  counter-increment: sub-counter; 
  content: counter(css-counters) "." counter(sub-counter) " "; 
  position: absolute; 
  left: -60px;
  top: 0; 
}
<body contenteditable="true">
  <div class="first">
    CẤP HẠN MỨC TÍN DỤNG:
    <div class="second">
      <span id="dieu1_key4" class="bold">Hạn Mức Tín Dụng:</span>
      <span id='dieu1_key5'>...</span>
    </div>
    <div class="second">
      <span id="dieu1_key4" class="bold">Hạn Mức Tín Dụng:</span>
      <span id='dieu1_key5'>...</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="first">
    CẤP TÍN DỤNG THEO HẠN MỨC TÍN DỤNG
  </div>
</body>




why not use an ol in the first place?

I found the solution: just a minor change in css


    body {
        counter-reset: css-counters 0;
      }
      .first {
        position: relative;
        left: 90px;
        right: auto;
        bottom: auto;
        padding: 10px;
      }

      .first:before {
        counter-increment: css-counters;
        content: "Điều " counter(css-counters) " ";
        position: absolute;
        left: -60px;
        top: 10px;
        counter-reset: sub-counter;
      }

      .first .second {
        position: relative;
      }

      .first .second:before {
        counter-increment: sub-counter;
        content: counter(css-counters) "." counter(sub-counter) " ";
        position: absolute;
        left: -60px;
        top: 0;
      }
<body contenteditable="true">
  <div class="first">
    CẤP HẠN MỨC TÍN DỤNG:
    <div class="second">
      <span id="dieu1_key4" class="bold">Hạn Mức Tín Dụng:</span>
      <span id='dieu1_key5'>...</span>
    </div>
    <div class="second">
      <span id="dieu1_key4" class="bold">Hạn Mức Tín Dụng:</span>
      <span id='dieu1_key5'>...</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="first">
    CẤP TÍN DỤNG THEO HẠN MỨC TÍN DỤNG
  </div>
</body>




You are defining your sub-counter to increment by 0. Here's the fixed code.


body {
  counter-reset: css-counters 0; 
}
.first {
  position: relative;
  left: 90px;
  top: 10px;
  right: auto;
  bottom: auto;
  padding: 10px;
}

.first:before {
  counter-increment: css-counters; 
  content: "Điều " counter(css-counters) " "; 
  position: absolute; 
  left: -60px; 
  top: 0; 
}

.first .second {
  counter-reset: sub-counter; 
  position: relative; 
}

.first .second:first-child {
  counter-reset: sub-counter; 
}

.first .second:not(:first-child) {
  counter-increment: sub-counter; // Here remove the 0 or set it to 1
}

.first .second:before {
  counter-increment: sub-counter; 
  content: counter(css-counters) "." counter(sub-counter) " "; 
  position: absolute; 
  left: -60px;
  top: 0; 
}
<body contenteditable="true">
  <div class="first">
    CẤP HẠN MỨC TÍN DỤNG:
    <div class="second">
      <span id="dieu1_key4" class="bold">Hạn Mức Tín Dụng:</span>
      <span id='dieu1_key5'>...</span>
    </div>
    <div class="second">
      <span id="dieu1_key4" class="bold">Hạn Mức Tín Dụng:</span>
      <span id='dieu1_key5'>...</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="first">
    CẤP TÍN DỤNG THEO HẠN MỨC TÍN DỤNG
  </div>
</body>



